# Cannot get past FrameLocator of IFrame to get the content in it

Tags: playwright, playwright-typescript

I am trying to scrap some specific details from a webpage which has nested IFrames.

I go down the hierarchy with multiple locator and frame locator calls but I cannot seems to access the content of the final IFrame I reach.

The relevant code

```js
    const epubDiv = page.frameLocator('iframe[id="epubReader"]').locator(`//div[@id='fixed-book-frame' and contains(@class, 'fixed-book-frame')]`)

    const bookDiv = epubDiv.locator(`//*[@id="fixed-book-frame"]/div`)

    const subFrame = bookDiv.frameLocator('iframe[id="scaler"]')

    const subSubFrame = subFrame.frameLocator('html')
```

I am not certain the subSubFrame is even found, it doesn't timeout and there is an output when logging it so it seems to find it:

```
FrameLocator {
  _frame: <ref *1> Frame {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: 0,
    _connection: Connection {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _objects: [Map],
      onmessage: [Function (anonymous)],
      _lastId: 10,
      _callbacks: Map(0) {},
      _rootObject: [Root],
      _closedError: undefined,
      _isRemote: false,
      _localUtils: [LocalUtils],
      _rawBuffers: true,
      toImpl: [Function (anonymous)],
      _tracingCount: 0,
      _instrumentation: {},
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    _parent: Page {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: 0,
      _connection: [Connection],
      _parent: [BrowserContext],
      _objects: [Map],
      _type: 'Page',
      _guid: 'page@bd072daac0461c488c9c3a06b26725ec',
      _channel: [EventEmitter],
      _initializer: [Object],
      _logger: undefined,
      _instrumentation: {},
      _eventToSubscriptionMapping: [Map],
      _wasCollected: false,
      _browserContext: [BrowserContext],
      _ownedContext: undefined,
      _mainFrame: [Circular *1],
      _frames: [Set],
      _workers: Set(0) {},
      _closed: false,
      _closedOrCrashedScope: [LongStandingScope],
      _viewportSize: [Object],
      _routes: [],
      accessibility: [Accessibility],
      coverage: [Coverage],
      keyboard: [Keyboard],
      mouse: [Mouse],
      request: [APIRequestContext],
      touchscreen: [Touchscreen],
      _bindings: Map(0) {},
      _timeoutSettings: [TimeoutSettings],
      _video: null,
      _opener: null,
      _closeReason: undefined,
      _closeWasCalled: false,
      _harRouters: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    _objects: Map(2) {
      'handle@ac47ec83d8fcab52600d5365f792374f' => [ElementHandle],
      'handle@7a153072881e26304a0a0f235164facf' => [ElementHandle]
    },
    _type: 'Frame',
    _guid: 'frame@cfc978cd6c0a35e423e4be10e35be94e',
    _channel: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _object: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    _initializer: { url: 'about:blank', name: '', loadStates: [Array] },
    _logger: undefined,
    _instrumentation: {},
    _eventToSubscriptionMapping: Map(0) {},
    _wasCollected: false,
    _eventEmitter: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: 0,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    _loadStates: Set(4) { 'commit', 'domcontentloaded', 'load', 'networkidle' },
    _parentFrame: null,
    _url: 'https://biblio.manuel-numerique.com/',
    _name: '',
    _detached: false,
    _childFrames: Set(3) { [Frame], [Frame], [Frame] },
    _page: Page {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: 0,
      _connection: [Connection],
      _parent: [BrowserContext],
      _objects: [Map],
      _type: 'Page',
      _guid: 'page@bd072daac0461c488c9c3a06b26725ec',
      _channel: [EventEmitter],
      _initializer: [Object],
      _logger: undefined,
      _instrumentation: {},
      _eventToSubscriptionMapping: [Map],
      _wasCollected: false,
      _browserContext: [BrowserContext],
      _ownedContext: undefined,
      _mainFrame: [Circular *1],
      _frames: [Set],
      _workers: Set(0) {},
      _closed: false,
      _closedOrCrashedScope: [LongStandingScope],
      _viewportSize: [Object],
      _routes: [],
      accessibility: [Accessibility],
      coverage: [Coverage],
      keyboard: [Keyboard],
      mouse: [Mouse],
      request: [APIRequestContext],
      touchscreen: [Touchscreen],
      _bindings: Map(0) {},
      _timeoutSettings: [TimeoutSettings],
      _video: null,
      _opener: null,
      _closeReason: undefined,
      _closeWasCalled: false,
      _harRouters: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  _frameSelector: `iframe[id="epubReader"] >> internal:control=enter-frame >> //div[@id='fixed-book-frame' and contains(@class, 'fixed-book-frame')] >> //*[@id="fixed-book-frame"]/div >> iframe[id="scaler"] >> internal:control=enter-frame >> html`
}
```

The element supposedly found by subSubFrame, excluding informations that would allow to find the website, and indicating which data I am trying to obtain:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr" style="opacity: 1;">
<head><base href="THIS IS THE ONE OF THE PIECES OF DATA I'M TRYING TO EXTRACT" /><script type="text/javascript">(function injectedScript(){navigator.epubReadingSystem=window.parent.navigator.epubReadingSystem})()</script>
<title> TITLE </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fontface.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fl.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1152, height=1624" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="NON RELEVANT DATA" type="text/css" /></head>
<body style="width: 1152px; height: 1624px; touch-action: pinch-zoom;">
<div class="page" style="overflow:hidden;top:0px;left:0px;width:1152px;height:1624px;background-image:url('Images/Page_226216.jpg');background-size:1152px 1624px">
<a id="Target_Page_226216"><!--e--></a><div class="block" style="top:151px;left:83px;z-index:0;width:986px;height:742px;"><pre></pre></div><div class="line e" style="margin-left:0;margin-right:0;top:138px;left:81px;width:200px;z-index:2;height:39px;opacity:0"><div class="valig" style="height:39px"><pre></pre></div><span class="h" lang="fr-FR" xml:lang="fr-FR"><span style="font-size:0px;margin-right:34px"> </span> La <span style="word-spacing:0px">situation</span></span></div>
<div class="line f" style="margin-left:0;margin-right:0;top:180px;left:83px;width:50px;z-index:2;height:29px;opacity:0;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center"><div class="valig" style="height:29px"><pre></pre></div><span class="i" lang="fr-FR" xml:lang="fr-FR">Te</span><span class="i" lang="fr-FR" xml:lang="fr-FR"><span style="word-spacing:0px">xte</span></span></div>

</div>
<script id="jouveEmbeddedMessage" type="text/javascript" src="/lib/embedded.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

This html element has a body:

```html
<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="width: 1152px; height: 1624px; touch-action: pinch-zoom;">
<div class="page" style="overflow:hidden;top:0px;left:0px;width:1152px;height:1624px;background-image:url('THIS IS ANOTHER PIECE OF DATA I AM TRYING TO EXTRACT');background-size:1152px 1624px">
<a id="Target_Page_226216"><!--e--></a><div class="block" style="top:151px;left:83px;z-index:0;width:986px;height:742px;"><pre></pre></div><div class="line e" style="margin-left:0;margin-right:0;top:138px;left:81px;width:200px;z-index:2;height:39px;opacity:0"><div class="valig" style="height:39px"><pre></pre></div><span class="h" lang="fr-FR" xml:lang="fr-FR"><span style="font-size:0px;margin-right:34px"> </span> La <span style="word-spacing:0px">situation</span></span></div>
<div class="line f" style="margin-left:0;margin-right:0;top:180px;left:83px;width:50px;z-index:2;height:29px;opacity:0;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center"><div class="valig" style="height:29px"><pre></pre></div><span class="i" lang="fr-FR" xml:lang="fr-FR">Te</span><span class="i" lang="fr-FR" xml:lang="fr-FR"><span style="word-spacing:0px">xte</span></span></div>

</div>
<script id="jouveEmbeddedMessage" type="text/javascript" src="/lib/embedded.js"></script></body>
```

I can't seem to get this data.

First I tried to switch the frameLocator to a frame using

```js
await subSubFrame.locator(':root').evaluate(() => document.documentElement.outerHTML)
```

Which I found here: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/22279

This didn't work, I then tried to use a locator to get the div in the body:

```js
const bodyDiv = subSubFrame.locator('div[class="page"]')
```

Did not work either, I then tried to us css for the locator but I couldn't make it work either:

```js
const bodyDiv = subSubFrame.locator('body > *:first-child')
```

I don't really know how to proceed from here. Thanks in advance to anyone that took the time to read this and might be able to help me.

Comment: I don't see any iframes in your markup.